# Adding JQuery/Javascript Files to Project

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a project I am working on at work that is ASP.NET in TFS.  I have checked out the solution and have made some adjustments to the code behind with no issues.  When I try to add JQuery and a Javascript file to the project, it does it fine in Visual Studio 2012.  But when rebuilding and running it won't execute the javascript code.  It's like it ignores it.  When I put breakpoints in the Javascript file I get the message 'The breakpoint will not currently be hit, no symbols have been loaded for this document'. I simply cannot get the web page to acknowlegde either the JS file, or the JQuery file.

(And yes, I have scoured StackOverflow.com and tried all the suggestions mentioned)

Any suggestions appreciated!

Comment: When you have strange problems like this it's best to break it down into a simple example.  Try to create a test html page that includes your .js file and see if it loads it and executes a method. Maybe alerts "Hello World" on load or something similar.  If that works then try it with an aspx page and continue to work it out until you find the issue.

Comment: Have you try the network tool of your browser ? (most likely : F12 > Network). Is your script loaded ? What is the http code returned ?

Comment: Thanks for the response, the ASP page WILL render inline javascript code.  ( I did an alert("Hello World!") and it popped up).

Comment: Then you probably aren't loading the .js file correctly.  As suggested, use the developer tools console to see any potential errors.

Comment: This has nothing to do with TFS -- I removed the TFS tag from the question and the title.